# How to access a string in char array

Tags: c++, oop

in a Morse code game i making a char array as shown below, i want to get each element as array [ index ]; but it gives segmentation fault. can any one give the solution.

```
const char * const array[3]={"apple","mango","banana"};
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/9WAf6M

Comment: No, nobody can give the solution without knowing what the problem is. Nobody can know what the problem is without seeing your code.

Comment: what's your code for ' getting each element '

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted the code showing the segfault, so it's hard to give a complete analysis of what might be causing it. However, it's likely that what you're accessing is outside the bounds of the array the words are stored in, which throws a segmentation error.

As for a solution, why not use an STL container? Something along the lines of a `std::vector` would work just fine:

```
//Container that stores words
std::vector<std::string> MorseWords;

//To add a word
MorseWords.push_back("apple");

//To access a letter within a word
char letter = MorseWords[WordPosition][LetterPosition];
```

The following example uses the above principle:

```
std::vector<std::string> MorseWords;
MorseWords.push_back("apple");
MorseWords.push_back("banana");
MorseWords.push_back("carrot");

std::cout << MorseWords[1][0]; //Prints the 'b' of banana
```